# Switching from Python 2.7.* to 2.6.8 Mac Os X 10.8.2

Tags: python, unix, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

Please keep in mind I am not overly proficient at Terminal/Unix.

I originally installed some version of python 2.7, and now need to run an older version (2.6.8). With your help thus far (plus a lot of trouble shooting and scary deleting of things that said python2.7 etc etc).

Initially I did the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
```

And then tried:

```
cd /usr/local/bin; 

ls -l . | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

I thought I did everything to uninstall 2.7, then ran the `"./configure"` in the 2.6.8 folder, which seemed to have worked, except:

When I typed `"python --version"` into the command line and it was supposed to give back Python 2.6.8, it would return:

```
Python 2.7.2
```

So then I deleted/removed some other files that seemed to need removal 
based on info from the same page that supplied the other commands, trying to:

remove the symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin`

(I do know which ones, and can supply that info as needed), now it returns:

```
"python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory"
```

Which is clearly no good either. And I get the same response when I try to run python from the command line. How do I fix this/get it to look for 2.6.8?

Comment: Is there a reason you are compiling by hand?

Comment: Also, what reason do you have to *need* 2.6.8? It's an outdated version.

Comment: I need to run numpy, scipy, and Vpython. And the 2.6.8 version, to my knowledge (according to the readme) says i need to compile by hand. If that's not the case, then I am totally willing to do it in the gui

Comment: None of those dependencies require an old version of Python, as far as I can see. Why do you think they do? (It wouldn't really make sense for that to be the case, as within the 2.x branch, Python didn't make breaking changes - so anything that worked in 2.6 should work in 2.7 (albeit not in 3.x or the other way around)).

Comment: It is for a physics class, and the previous students found for OS X it would *only* work with 2.6. I do know that the numpy website says the latest version is   numpy-1.6.2-py2.6-python.org-macosx10.3.dmg  which seems to point to py2.6. I don't know about the other programs yet, but the previous students seemed pretty clear about needing 2.6

Comment: Quote: "So I really did get Elect.py to work on my mac... and without the previous lag. I had to install vpython, ipython, and scipy by themselves. Little tricky how to do this but I thought I would include it here:

First you have to have python version 2.6, nothing higher (2.7, 3.0) and nothing lower (2.5)"